# eclipselink and netbeans java desktop application jdialog not launching

Tags: java

I developed a small payroll app in netbeans, it seems to be working fine when I run it, I clean and built it,now I have the jar file in the dist folder and the eclipselink libraries ,derby and all that in the lib folder. My problem is a particular jdialog that connects to the entitymanager that makes me view some database entries is not launching,I have tried it for two netbeans database apps,but its not working too.but it launches in the IDE fine,what could be the error? There is no stack track whatsoever

Comment: Welcome to stackoverlflo please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq for asking questions.

Comment: Can this question be answered please

Comment: How are you running the application?  Double clicking it? From the command line?

Comment: @Madprogrammer,I just tried running it on commandline,and its showing me that the table doesn't exist,  table/view 'mauranagroup" doesnot exist,how to I solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans is a tool which added required jarfile automatically to your classpat for your main application. but when you are trying to run manually you missing out the classpath whcih is required to run main application.

You need to write a .bat file set your classpath in bat file and at the end run your main program.

Comment: My program builds to the dist folder as jar,and the libraries required,swingworker,eclipselink,derby are all there,but the jdialog to show the entries is not appearing when I launch it,but launches in the ide,guess this doesn't answer my question (the .bat file)

Comment: Ok how you are launching other than ide.

Comment: I launch it in a jar file ,containing all the files, the aboutbox dialog which is part of the package launches,since its not connected to a persistence unit ,but the other dialog connected to a persistence unit doesn't,but it launches in the ide,where it is been tested